# How to generate random variables for email address using jmeter automation?

Tags: jmeter

I want to enter email address in the field for registration form.

Is it possible to give the format of email address and automatically generate that email address with the given format when I run the script?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

There are few options,

1. See [article](http://testingfreak.com/how-to-pass-random-emails-in-webpage-using-jmeter/) about saving it in `User Parameters` Email variable with value `${__V(Test10${__Random(1,10000,)}@gmail.com)}`
2. You can use Jmeter [functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString)

> ${__RandomString(5)} will return a random string of 5 characters which
>   can be readable or not

and add it to request as ${__RandomString(5)}@gmail.com

3. You can use [Random Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable) with Output Format as:

> "USER_000" which will generate output of the form USER_nnn.

Answer (score 0):

For Generate Random email in Jmeter use the below customize the method:

```
${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite option:

```
${__substring(${__UUID()}, 0, 8)}.${__substring(${__UUID()}, 25, 35)}@gmail.com
```

NOTE: the `substring` function is provided by the [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As per Using JMeter Functions guide __RandomString() function takes 3 parameters:

- Length of the desired random string
- Source characters

If you need to store generated string into a JMeter variable you can provide variable name as 3rd argument.
So to get line of 10 alphabet characters you can use __RandomString function as follows:

```
${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}
```